# Is it possible to stop Intellij from formatting comment blocks?

Tags: intellij-idea, javadoc

Our company requires that we put a formatted comment block at the top of all our files with copyright information in it. It's easy enough to automate the generation of this through the file templates, but I'm having a problem in that IntelliJ insists on applying code formatting to the comment block and removes a lot of the formatting spaces. So that this:

```
/************************************************************
 *                                                          *
 * Contents of file Copyright (c) The Company 2015          *
 *                                                          *
 *----------------------------------------------------------*
 *                                                          *
 * WARNING:                                                 *
 * Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. *
 * Cras imperdiet mi nec urna lacinia, facilisis molestie   *
 * augue lacinia. Curabitur sagittis vestibulum ultrices.   *
 *                                                          *
 * Vestibulum et ante sed libero vestibulum cursus a        *
 * consectetur augue. Pellentesque tristique imperdiet      *
 * lacinia. Fusce ac magna justo. Donec hendrerit nunc ut   *
 * odio fermentum, sit amet fermentum leo tempor. Mauris    *
 * vestibulum dui risus, vel rutrum nulla fermentum quis.   *
 *                                                          *
 * Duis quis iaculis enim, feugiat ultricies mi...          *
 *                                                          *
 ************************************************************/
```

becomes this:

```
/************************************************************
 * *
 * Contents of file Copyright (c) The Company 2015          *
 * *
 * ----------------------------------------------------------*
 * *
 * WARNING:                                                 *
 * Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. *
 * Cras imperdiet mi nec urna lacinia, facilisis molestie   *
 * augue lacinia. Curabitur sagittis vestibulum ultrices.   *
 * *
 * Vestibulum et ante sed libero vestibulum cursus a        *
 * consectetur augue. Pellentesque tristique imperdiet      *
 * lacinia. Fusce ac magna justo. Donec hendrerit nunc ut   *
 * odio fermentum, sit amet fermentum leo tempor. Mauris    *
 * vestibulum dui risus, vel rutrum nulla fermentum quis.   *
 * *
 * Duis quis iaculis enim, feugiat ultricies mi...          *
 * *
 ************************************************************/
```

Unfortunately I can't change the content of the block, so my only option lies within IntelliJ's configuration (if it even lies there). Everything's formatted fine when I create the file, but if I ever run the code formatting tool, it gets messed up.

Comment: Did you know there is a `Copyright` plugin in the IntelliJ repository? From memory (its been a while since I used it), it can automatically update the copyright message in any source file that is checked in to VCS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can disable JavaDoc formatting completely.

Go to Settings -> Editor-> Code Style -> JAVA -> JavaDoc Tab and **uncheck** *Enable JavaDoc Formatting*. Hope that does it

Comment: You're an absolute lifesaver and legend of a person! This worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Lol that's a bit too much. Glad I could help! Just accept the answer so that does it :)

Comment: Yeah it wouldn't let me accept it straight away. I've been trying to fix this on and off for a couple of months, I just kept having to fix it manually where I hand't realised I'd done it again, very annoying.

Comment: Oh just a heads up. If you have any obscure query about IntelliJ that isn't fit for SO, @jetserge on twitter is THE guy.